# Option to "watch" a proposal on Area51

Tags: feature-request, area-51

I would like to keep track of a proposal **without** following it.  Rather than searching for the proposal each time I'd like it to appear on my summary page.  Using a "watch" option, to keep track of it without adding my support.

The reason I want to do this is I proposed the [Aquarium Hobbyist](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1754/aquarium-hobbyist) site, and soon after a competing proposal was created; [Saltwater Aquariums](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2102/saltwater-aquariums).  I think the second site is *too* focused and so I don't want to "follow" it but I would like to keep track of its' progress.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be getting RSS feed of that proposal

> http://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/proposal/2102

Comment: Good option, but I'd still rather have it show up on my summary page.